# How to call Ubercart functionality using Drupal 7 rest services?

Tags: ubercart, services

I am using Drupal 7 with Services module for our phonegap application. 
In that web application we are using Ubercart module for payment gatway method. I am fetching product list from web service but how can I handle payment method from Drupal service?